# Adding elements to a collection when the mouse is clicked

Tags: java, collections, concurrency

I have seen many questions close to this one on this site, but not this exact one, so I will ask anyway. Apologies if this is a duplicate.

I have a HashSet containing Points, which are displayed in a window. Since the Points are moving all the time, I need to always iterate over my HashSet in order to update the window. All in all, my main loop looks something like this:

```
HashSet<Point> h = ...
while(true){
  for(Point p : h){
    p.update();
    draw(p);
  }
}
```

Now here is where things go south. I would like that, when the user clicks somewhere on the screen, a Point is added at this place. However, naive approach to add an element to the HashSet directly in the event handler fails, because you cannot modify it while it is being iterated. Base code of the naive approach:

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
  h.add(new Point(e.getX, e.getY));
}
```

An idea I had in order to avoid that behaviour was to maintain a temporary List in which the points to add would be kept, waiting for the main iteration over the HashSet to finish in order to add the new points. But that doesn't really seem safe to me, since an (unlucky) user could manage to add a point *while the List is being iterated*.

So what is the Best Practice solution here?

Comment: Can you add code, please.

Comment: Without any code to know how your painting and updating process works, a simple solution might to synchronise the set so it can't be iterated while it's been updated

Comment: @MartinKrüger I tried to add some. Let me know if this is still not enough.

Answer (score 1):

This is Swing and Swing is single threaded, so this is not a problem. Simply

- get rid of the `while (true)` loop,
- And don't try to iterate repeatedly and instantaneously as that leads to disaster.
- use a [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) instead with a reasonable delay between iterations
- Now threading won't be an issue since you cannot be adding a Point to the list while it is being iterated through.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably have two identical HashSets, and add the value to the one you are not currently iterating over. Alternate between which one you iterate by simply having a boolean value.

Some pseudo-code would be:

```
HashSet h1 = [...]
HashSet h2 = [...]
boolean b = true;

[...]

if(b) {
    iterateOver(h1);
    h1 = h2;
    b = !b;
} else {
    iterateOver(h2);
    h2 = h1;
    b = !b;
}

[...]

if(b) {
    h2.add();

} else {
    h1.add();
}

[...]
```

Comment: Unless you synchronize your `HashSet`s contents in your ellipses, you will get different point sets after some time.

Comment: I edited and added `h2 = h1` and `h1 = h2`. I forgot those.